# Handle Python reserved words in a sympy parse_expr?

Tags: python, sympy, python-exec

If I parse an expression containing `lambda`, I get an error even though `Symbol("lambda")` is valid:

```
>>> sympy.Symbol("lambda")
lambda
>>> sympy.parse_expr("1 + lambda")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "xxx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/parsing/sympy_parser.py", line 1008, in parse_expr
    return eval_expr(code, local_dict, global_dict)
  File "xxx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/parsing/sympy_parser.py", line 903, in eval_expr
    code, global_dict, local_dict)  # take local objects in preference
  File "<string>", line 1
    Integer (1 )+lambda
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> sympy.parse_expr("1 + _lambda")
_lambda + 1
```

I'd like to allow users of my code to name their variables how ever they like. Is there a way to support this?

If not, I could work out some other way to put an underscore in front of reserved words.

I'm using Sympy 1.6 if that matters.

Comment: The problem isn't with the `symbol`, but with the Python variable that usually looks the same.  Python variables cannot be reserved words.  Read the block about symbol names here https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html.  And study https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html.  It probably has parameters that let you control the translation from symbol names to variables in the global dict.

Comment: The only comment I find is confirmation that using `lambda` is a syntax error: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html#sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.lambda_notation
but no guidance on if it's possible to parse `"lambda"` as a symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Searching `sympy` for `reserved`, I found a suggestion to use `lamda` (without the 'b').  https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/matrices.html?highlight=reserved

```
In [146]: lamda = symbols('lamda')

In [147]: from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import standard_transformations

In [148]: parse_expr("1/2+lamda", transformations=standard_transformations)
Out[148]: λ + 1/2
```

Comment: ah, good find! that didn't turn up in my searches. I think the answer to my question is: there is no way to use `lambda`, I'm going to have to either disallow that spelling from my users or implement a variable name mapping.